# Video Metadata Tags

Tags: c#, video, metadata, mp4, avi

I'm trying to develop a simple application to edit the Metadata "seasonNumber", "episodeNumber" and "TV Show", that appears in the "Media Information" of the VLC, but I'm familiar only with C# and I search already for 2 weeks trying to find what kind of Metadata/Tag it is, but I couldn't, I already tried TagLib#, and AppleTags, but when I do It does not appear in the "VLC Media Information", can you guys give me a hint?

Note: I'm trying to do this in MP4 and AVI files.

Comment: You could take a look at exiftool's tag name pages for [RIFF](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/RIFF.html) and [Quicktime](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html) metadata.  The Quicktime page has `TVEpisode` and `TVSeason` which is probably what you're looking for.  Do you have an AVI file where these tags appear, as I don't see anything on the RIFF page that would be similar.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that VLC does not necessarily obtain the seasonNumber and episodeNumber from the file metadata. I've made a quick look on its source code and I've found the fields resolving logic in 2 places:

1. filename.lua: https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/share/lua/meta/reader/filename.lua
2. TitleAnalyzers.cpp: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/medialibrary/blob/master/src/utils/TitleAnalyzer.cpp

As you can see, in both cases it's just a regex invoked on the file name. And indeed, if you change the "S[0-9]+E[0-9]+" part of the file name, VLC would display the new values.